# Is there a nanosleep function for "struct timeval" in MacOS?

Tags: c++, c, macos

I have a problem recording a time interval (measured in millisecond at least) in my MacOS (OS X El Capitan 10.11.2).

Obviously the basic idea is recording the time twice and make subtraction. The problem happened when I found there is gettimeofday() in "sys/time.h" and a struct for this function - struct timeval. Then I got the time interval and wanted to make it sleep according to the time interval. However, it seems either nanosleep() or usleep() doesn't have an argument of timeval type (ignored sleep() since I need millisecond at least).

Should I convert timeval to fit nanosleep() or usleep() or there is a better and simpler way?

Comment: There aren't any standard conversion functions back and forth between `struct timeval` that I know of; generally you have to roll your own.

Comment: you can use function like `select` without any FDs with `timeval` argument.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes and it seems tedious. I bet there is a better way.

Comment: @SHR didn't use select before, I may figure it out, ty

Comment: There's `usleep(useconds_t nap)`, but it doesn't take a `struct timeval`.  I'd write a wrapper — maybe `int microsleep(const struct timeval *nap) { return usleep(nap->tv_sec * 1000000 + nap->tv_usec); }` — or maybe I'd take some care about overflows, etc.  There's also `nanosleep()` which takes a `struct timespec`; you could write a wrapper to convert the `struct timeval` to `struct timespec` and use that.  No need to check for overflows; simply multiply the `tv_usec` value by 1000 to get the `tv_nsec` value.  So, wrapping is what I'd do in your situation.

Comment: If you're not already aware of them, you might look up the macros/functions (which are available on Mac/BSD, and may be available under GNU if you get `__USE_BSD` defined): `void timeradd(struct timeval *a, struct timeval *b, struct timeval *res);`
`void timersub(struct timeval *a, struct timeval *b, struct timeval *res);`,
`void timerclear(struct timeval *tvp);`,
`int timerisset(struct timeval *tvp);`,
`int timercmp(struct timeval *a, struct timeval *b, CMP);`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree, I think long int to take care of tv_sec*1000 + tv_usec/1000 is enough, isn't it? No need to check overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample uses `select` to sleep on `timeval` value (here it is for 10 seconds):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf("start...\n");
    struct timeval tv = {10, 0};
    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    printf("done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `select()` can be interrupted by a signal, and will return early if this happens.

Comment: Fun fact:  this trick won’t work under Windows (because windows’ implementation of select() errors out if you don’t pass in at least one socket)